# Could Wolverine's claws be prevented from unsheathing if his wrists are bent?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine

When retracted, Wolverine's claws are stored in his arms. In order to unsheathed them, they must pass though his wrist and move along the space between his knuckles.

Due to the way Wolverine's claws come out of his hands, could they be blocked within his arm if his wrists are bent one way or the other? If yes, was this technique ever be used against him?

Comment: Just want to verify: you meant to ask about his wrists being bent or not, correct? I edited it to reflect that, but originally the title said "banded." I think from context, bent is what you were looking for, though. Blue's answer below reflects the "banded" idea.

Comment: @GabeWillard You are right, I was thinking about something like a [Wristlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wristlock).

Comment: Okay. Just wanted to make sure. :)

Comment: Based on this question, can he even bend his hands at the wrist?

Comment: @Wikis If he cannot, this would somewhat answer the question.

Comment: We have seen that Wolverine himself can hold back individual claws, so it stands that you would be able to hold them in. His own flesh wouldn't be able to stop them, but if aimed properly his bones would.
Of course, this would be similar to holding a sword back by pressing something against the tip. To my knowledge no one has tried to use his own wrist to hold them in, Wolverine would likely just slice through his own hand to get out of it (the bones would have to be lined up completely flawlessly to hold them in with a wrist-lock).

Comment: @GorchestopherH Did you mean to place this as a comment or an answer?

Comment: @KevinHowell It's just a comment as to my opinion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends on whether or not Wolverines claws are controlled by a set of muscles in his forearms or wrist that require the right position before they come out. If there are separate muscles which control his claws then it's very possible that a wristlock could keep them from coming out. Since his claws can cut through anything except his bones though they could come out of an area other than between his knuckles. So as long as a wristlock does not somehow incapacitate his triggering muscles (if they even exist) then he would still be able to have his claws come out and it would be painful.

Comment: Isn't it *always* painful?

Comment: @IsziRoryorIsznti yes to quote the movie "every time" but the standard way of coming out versus tearing through muscle and flesh and ligaments that it normally doesn't would cause a lot more pain especially since the muscles of the forearm may be continuously healing and getting shredded until he could retract them. I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: It seems that his claws are controlled by some muscles in his forearms. So, wrist-lock would only stop his claws with perfect placement or by making him not want to shred his hands, which we all know, he wouldn't care.

Comment: +1 for the mention of the _**pain**_, but I don't think you emphasized just how much more _**painful**_ it would be.

Answer (score 17):

**No - if Wolverine's wrist was bent, the claws would just emerge from the wrist instead.**

In fact, this very thing occurs in [Wolverines #11](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Wolverines_Vol_1_11) (2015). In a flashback, it is revealed that a heavily-intoxicated Wolverine once popped his claws through his wrists by accident:

[image]

Years before that, however, in the 1995 "Age of Apocalypse" arc we saw a [version](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/James_Howlett_(Earth-295)) of Wolverine who had lost his left hand altogether. Most enemies assumed that this meant the claws on that arm were useless, but learned the hard way that the claws could still emerge directly from the severed wrist:

[image]

---

**Speculation:**

Now, all that said, it still doesn't answer the question of whether or not Logan's adamantium-covered bones would prevent the claws from emerging. I wasn't able to find any examples of that occurring, but if I had to speculate, I would imagine that the claws would STILL pop out regardless.

Keep in mind that the claws are just bone (albeit extremely dense, hard bone) attached to muscles within the forearm. These bones, even when covered in metal, would have a certain degree of flexibility at the attachment point. Therefore, if one or all claws met resistance when moving outward, the muscle would flex and the tip would just move along that axis until the resistance stopped. The claw(s) would move inside the emergence path, and it would probably hurt like blazes, but they would still come out. Or the muscle/tendons would tear apart, in which case the claw would THEN move and come out in the wrong place such as the top/bottom of the arm.

---

**Differences between movie and comic versions:**

It's also important to note a major difference between the movie & comic versions of Wolverine. In the comics, any anatomical references seemed to indicate that the claws were positioned *above* the arm bones, and thus emerged through the upper part of the hand and out just above the knuckles:

[image]

In the movies, however, the claws are positioned *between* the arm bones (which are split apart at the wrist), and emerge through the hand bones, pushing them out of the way and emerging directly between the knuckles instead of above them:

[image]

This difference may seem minor, but it is vital to the question since the initial position of the bones within the arm would not only determine IF they could be deflected by the arm bones, but also which direction they would go when it happened.

Comment: Is one of the characters on the left Wolverine, or what's going on here?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - lol, yep, the one with the metal cap on his wrist is "Weapon X", the AoA version of Logan. In that reality, Cyclops is a bad guy and vaporized his hand when they fought years prior.

Comment: But then what are we looking at on the right?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - updated the image with sources AND hand-drawn red circles.

Comment: Why didn't the AoA Wolverine's hand grow back?

Comment: Is that a question mark floating in the air in the right picture? Under the speech bubble? And how did Logan get intoxicated anyway? I thought his healing factor prevented that.

Comment: @DCShannon - he got intoxicated after drinking some alien concoction on Knowhere (the celestial head/space station from GotG). The "question mark" looking thing is actually the hose he just drank out of. Google "wolverines 11 drunk" and you can see the whole thing.

Comment: @Omegacron, Oh, I didn't realize those pictures were from different comics and I couldn't figure out why the appearance was different between two adjacent frames.

Comment: I updated the format of the answer and made them separate images. That should make things clearer.

Comment: @Omegacron:   It looks like you should answer [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150472/does-logan-wolverine-get-drunk)

Comment: Also, I would add, this even though this is a great answer, which answers the letter of the question, I wonder it if really fits the intent.   The intent seems to be, *Can you prevent the claws from coming out by blocking them it other of Wolverine's adamantium-covered bones?*   But in the first image, the claws are presumably going over the [carpals](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/2c/31/f3/2c31f380cb58bc0f9b5be4aa0a6dbcd6.jpg) (as usual) and between the metacarpals, and in the second, there are no bones in the way at all.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I see what you mean, but I doubt we can answer that without speculation. I'll throw it in, just to cover my bases. The answer is more for info than anything else, given that there's already an accepted answer from earlier.