# Has Wolverine ever changed the silicon seals in his hands?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine

According to the 1991 Marvel Trading Cards set, Wolverine has "silicon seals" in his hands which "must be periodically replaced".

[image: claws image]

This card, however, is from before it was revealed that Wolverine had natural bone claws (see: X-Men 25 from 1993) and *possibly** before the revelation that the claws were not exactly "implanted" as everyone previously believed (see: Marvel Comics Presents 72-84 from 1991)

The fact that the card mentions stainless steel  penetration slots, and the idea that the claws are "attached" to the skeleton, coupled with the information revealed later brings doubt on the accuracy and reliability of anything on the card.

**Have the supposed "silicon seals" been mentioned *anywhere* in the comics other than this card? Has he ever actually had to change them?**

To be clear, I am looking for in-*story* mention, not just a mention in a reference guide. Some instance where the silicon seals are mentioned as existing or requiring maintenance.

* <sup>I can't find an exact release date for the trading cards, and it is likely that the cards were in production prior to the publication of Marvel Comics Presents.</sup>

Comment: I haven't heard of this from any other sources. I wouldn't be surprised if this was the only mention of this since this series might not be necessarily taking information from canonical sources. I doubt that Stan Lee would have the time to write the summary for these cards. I am just speculating though. It would be interesting to see some good answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How exactly do Wolverine's claws come out?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17298/how-exactly-do-wolverines-claws-come-out)

Comment: The other answer (and the one you posted here) show possible evidence (though, not in-comic) of the silicon, but both fail to address the issue of whether or not they've ever been changed.

Comment: Wow. I've been an avid Wolverine fan since the 80s, and this is the first I've heard of any silicon seals. Weird little detail.

Answer (score 7):

Mentioned again? Yup.

The silicon seals are referenced on this art card by Wolverine artist Sean Chen from the [Marvel Ultimate Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0756620058) to the X-Men

[image]

Comment: So they are mentioned again... albeit again in a sort of Reference guide.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - Yup.

Comment: Hasn't all this been redacted from the canon to instead focus on Wolverine's healing aspect? This combination of physical characteristics seems less mutant and more mechanical/medical construct or surgical implants. Too high maintenance for loner Logan.

Comment: @IhorSypko - Yes, largely. The question wasn't "is this current canon" though, it's "have they ever been mentioned anywhere else" to which the answer is an emphatic yes.