# Where do Lady Deathstrike's blades go when not extended?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, mutant

Are Lady Deathstrike's blades segmented and retract into her finger tips as these photos seem to indicate? [image: Deathstrike1] [image: Deathstrike2]

Or is there another way that they are sheathed when not in use?

Comment: A question would be why are her eye to different colours in the images? One pic they are brown another they are grey/silver....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Much like Wolverine, they go into her forearm.

You can see the x-ray in the movie.

Much like Wolverine, [they really don't make any sense as far as how they're controlled.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/51786/5184)

When extended, there is a sort of segmented visual element to them.

[image: snikt]

This is slightly at odds with the x-rays visible in the movie, as when retracted, they are housed in her arms in a non-collapsed position. They exit her fingertips, but retract through the fingers, hand, and wrist.

[image: lady deathstrike x-rays]