# Has Wolverine ever had his claws ripped out?

Tags: marvel, comics, wolverine

Wolverine's claws are coated in adamantium just like his skeleton, but there is no direct adamantium connection between the two - the claws are attached to muscle & tendon, not bone. It seems to me that an opponent with sufficient strength should be able to grab the claws and rip them out of Wolverine's arm completely, severing the muscles and tendons holding them in place.

**Has Wolverine ever had his claws ripped out by an opponent?**

***Note:*** I am not interested in cases where the claws were broken - only cases where they were actually torn out of the arm by an enemy.

Comment: I've seen some chatter that Laura had her foot claws ripped out and then put back in but I haven't been able to confirm this. There is also an old rumor that Claremont had planned to write a story where Colossus would rip out Logan's claws entirely, but left before it ever got written.

Comment: There has been at least one or two stories where someone from the future had Wolverine's claws (not claws *like* his, but his actual claws). However, since we have only been shown the claws, not how they were obtained from him, we can't say whether they were broken, ripped out, or simply remove from his bare skeleton (with no remaining muscle and tendon, should be easily done).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In [Marvel Zombies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Zombies), a zombified Wolverine tries to use his claws against Silver Surfer. His arm bones (including his claws) rip through his skin and are "unsleeved" from his arm:

[image: zombie Wolverine vs Silver Surfer]

He then says:

> Can't think of what I'd rather have more right now -- a healing factor strong enough to fight decomposition or adamantium ligaments to hold these bones together.

That last panel shows his claws falling out now that he doesn't have the "meat" to hold them.