# Does Logan (Wolverine) get drunk?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

It's not difficult to find scenes of Logan drinking.

Here's one (NSFW)

## Does Logan get drunk?

If not, why does he drink?   If yes, shouldn't his healing factor make him immune to poisons?

Comment: *"..shouldn't his healing factor make him immune to poisons?"* Small amounts of alcohol are actually healthful, despite what the nanny state, anti-fun prod noses of public health would have us believe. [The **dose** makes the poison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G9Rc.png)..

Comment: There are in-comic examples of Logan getting drunk and sobering up very shortly after. The one I'm thinking of was back in the Mariko days, Wolvie got blasted and was complaining about how he couldn't really get drunk - while blind, stinking drunk. Narration indicates a very short while later (forget the exact time frame, less than an hour) and he's stone sober and meditating.

Comment: Show me where that question actually answers this one except for a quote from x-men.wikia which, being a wiki [**is not a primary source**](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7387/3823).  Please don't jump the gun on marking questions duplicate.    (Also,  alcoholism and drunkenness are not the same thing.)

Comment: Not everyone drinks to get drunk.

Comment: Because whiskey, et al. *tastes* good? If people only wanted to get drunk, they'd drink the cheapest vodka or malt liquor possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes - it's possible, although very difficult, for Logan to get drunk.**

Due to his healing factor, alcohol and other intoxicants do not affect Wolverine like they would a normal human. His system, even at low efficiency rates, burns the substance out of his system faster then he can feel the effects. Amounts that would kill a stout drinker from alcohol poisoning barely give him the "buzz" effect that would constitute "drunkenness".

That said, it IS possible under the right conditions for Logan to get drunk. It would require a continuous supply of the substance, and in a faster rate then what his body can burn out/consume. The same applies to any kind of sedative or medication, as seen in the original Weapon X comic as well as the "Enemy of the State" story arc:

[image: Comic panel where anaesthetics are explained to go out as quickly as they go in unless they can find the equilibrium amount]

In a flashback from Wolverines #11, we learn that Logan's friends once got him drunk using a continuous feed of a highly-powerful alien liquor:

[image: Logan gets drunk by drinking a massive amount of alcohol really quickly]

Comment: I thought you would use the image from your other answer that says "His healing factor metabolized the alcohol so fast that ten shots in a shot would only throw him off for a few seconds."

Comment: Sorry about that - I updated the image and included a second one concerning sedatives/anesthetics, as it's the same answer either way. A third example of how to beat the healing factor (which wasn't technically the question, but kinda is) was when they put a radioactive pellet inside The Native (basically a female version of Wolverine) to keep her system fighting that while they operated on her.

Comment: Checkmark.   Nice sources.   So you're a comic expert,  eh?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - LOL wouldn't consider myself an expert, no, but let's just say I haven't had much of a social life in 40 years and leave it at that

Comment: :)  Well,  I was really just trying to come up with an excuse to use *eh* like the good Canadian I am and not that idiocy where you just tack it onto every sentence (in reference to last panel).

Answer (score 4):

So Wolverine's healing factor doesn't stop injuries - it just heals them really fast.

I'd have to expect that he can feel the effects of the alcohol - but only for a really short time.

In fact - it would give him a really amazing capacity for putting away the hard stuff - which seems right in line with his entire character...

Comment: We seen many times it takes mere seconds for him to heal.   I challenge you to somehow get drunk fast enough if you become sober five seconds later.    He's not doing a continuous IV of pure alcohol.

Comment: Some people do just actually like the warm sting of strong liquor. Maybe Logan drinks rye because it reminds him of home (whether he can remember home specifically or not).

Answer (score 2):

I know Logan hasn't got exactly the same powers, but Captain America can't get drunk, he explains in [*Captain America: First Avenger*](https://www.reddit.com/r/plotholes/comments/1r6ne0/why_can_thor_get_intoxicated_but_not_captain/) that it is due to his enhanced metabolism.

So I suppose they *try* to get drunk or look bad-ass. Also maybe they are just interested by the taste...